# How to get fetchXml morerecords flag with XrmServiceToolkit

Tags: javascript, fetchxml, xrm

I am using XrmServiceToolkit to fetch data from a Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 server.
I want to limit the amount of results returned to a reasonable value, but i want to know if there are more results available to fire an alert or something similar.
The resultXml includes a flag named 'morerecords' for this reason.

My question is: Does anybody know how i can get this flag or at least the resultXml when using XrmServiceToolkit?